# openid connect authentication protocol in extranet network

Tags: openid, openid-connect, dotnetopenauth

I have a scenario where i have to use openID connect in extranet network. When an application initializes, it downloads the metadata document from .well-known/openid-configuration for which it makes a HTTP Get request. In extranet network with no internet connection , how can I get openid connect metadata document ? 
Can openID connect work without internet connection ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You do not require internet to use OpenID Connect. When I use the term internet, I refer to networks connecting general web sites or world wide web. Only requirement from protocol is the ability to use HTTP (and TLS) for communication among different roles (ex:- Client, Authorization server, resource server and end user).

You can use OpenID Connect inside an intranet. This network can be separated from internet. And it is possible to connect multiple intranets through VPN. Having a VPN will separate you from internet but allow to use HTTP communication.

So yes it is possible to use OpenID Connect without internet, but it require a network configuration as mentioned above.

Comment: Yes, that is an interesting answer. There has always been some misunderstanding going on when i discuss about internet , intranet and extranet with other application developers. Some developers say Internet is part of intranet and extranet, but they are different, right ?   How is HTTP communication enabled in extranet ? is it something network engineers do , being an application developer i would like to get more insight on this, if there are any online references  can you share , it would help me understand better.

Comment: This article (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/computer_fundamentals/computer_internet_intranet.htm) describe and gives a basic overview similar to my answer. Intranets can use a desired protocol for communication. HTTP is one such and many organizations maintain an intranet. This is done by network engineers. Also, when you use VPN, your communication is protected between networks but still can use internet to transmit data packets.

Answer (score 0):

If the client app cannot communicate with the outside world (but the user who wants to sign in to the app can), then you could:

- hard code the configuration values from the openid-configuration document in your app;
- do the same for the crypto keys referred to by the `jwks_uri`;
- use a `response type` (such as `id_token`) that does not require you to call the Token Endpoint from the app;
- (decrypt and) verify the ID Token you receive from the user's redirect locally in the app using the above crypto keys.

You may run into problems if the OpenID Provider rotates crypto keys frequently or irregularly, as you will need an out of band mechanism to keep those updated.